# outgoing internal links contain nofollow attribute? how to fix it in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nofollow

I'vre checked my website on semrush and i've got this issue (147 outgoing internal links contain nofollow attribute)- warning

So, how to fix it on wordpress?

Fixing outgoing internal links contain nofollow attribute to improve SEO

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.